# UNION don't want to return distinct values

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, distinct, union

I write script for full-text search by descriptions of some objects. But I did not satisfied with default full-text search algorithm in boolean mode, so I try to modify it some way. I want to combine 3 several searches into one. First query I search for "exact phrase", second - all words of phrase present, third - at least one of words is present. And then return it by priority. I must do something like this:

```
SELECT
    description,
    MATCH(description) AGAINST ('"my search"' in boolean mode) FROM search
    WHERE MATCH(description) AGAINST ('"my search"' in boolean mode)

UNION DISTINCT

SELECT
    description,
    MATCH(description) AGAINST ('+my +search' in boolean mode) FROM search
    WHERE MATCH(description) AGAINST ('+my +search' in boolean mode)

UNION

SELECT
    description,
    MATCH(description) AGAINST ('my* search*' in boolean mode) FROM search
    WHERE MATCH(description) AGAINST ('my* search*' in boolean mode)
```

As you can see, first block of rows will contain the most relevant results - exact phrase. Second block will contain less relevant rows, and third will contain all the rest.

But this query returns duplicated rows, in other words, row that exists in first block, can repeat again in second block, or third, even if I use UNION DISTINCT. But I want get global distinct set of rows for all three sub-selects. If row appears in first block, then it must not exist in seconds and third. How can I do this? Or may be you can give me more elegant solution for such kind of search?

Comment: maybe you can remove the `match(description)...` from the three selects and see what happens... that may deduplicate your results... or maybe you can enclose all your query inside a subquery: `select distinct description from (select... union select... union select...)`

Comment: Barranka, thank you! I see the problem was in match(desrctiption) in SELECT. I depreciatingly ignored it, because it was added for debugging reason, but now I see that of course it affect row's uniqueness. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

OK re-read problem.  Union all will give you all resutls, union should give you distinct results

Or you could just use

```
`Select distinct * from 
(SELECT
    description,
    MATCH(description) AGAINST ('"my search"' in boolean mode) FROM search
    WHERE MATCH(description) AGAINST ('"my search"' in boolean mode)

UNION DISTINCT

SELECT
    description,
    MATCH(description) AGAINST ('+my +search' in boolean mode) FROM search
    WHERE MATCH(description) AGAINST ('+my +search' in boolean mode)

UNION

SELECT
    description,
    MATCH(description) AGAINST ('my* search*' in boolean mode) FROM search
    WHERE MATCH(description) AGAINST ('my* search*' in boolean mode)) B`
```